# What is the ":" function in Racket?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/jbclements/midi-readwrite/blob/master/midi-readwrite/notestream.rkt)
which has expressions like

```
(: track->notes (MIDITrack -> (Listof Note)))
```

what is the `:` function?

I suspect it has something to do with contracts, but can't find a reference in the documentation.

Comment: No idea, but the Racket documentation supports token searches: http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=%3A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:`, in this context, means "has type". It is part of the *Typed Racket* extension, which adds static type checking to the language.

Your example states that the function `track->notes` accepts a `MIDITrack` and returns a list of `Note`s.

If you want to find out more, take a look at the [Typed Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/index.html).